# Prolog does not terminate on query with 2 arguments

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm new to Prolog and have a question to a programming exercise:

I have a program, that is for my opinion working most of the time, but with a specific query, I do not get an answer

```
is_number(0).
is_number(s(N)) :-
  is_number(N).

numberpair(pair(X,Y)) :-
  is_number(X),
  is_number(Y).

?- numberpair(pair(A,B)), A=s(s(0)), B=s(s(s(0))).
```

So I understand, that Prolog now tries every possible number for A and B -> [0,s(0),s(s(0)),s(s(s(0))), ...] but if it founds an answer for A (namely `s(s(0))`) it fails at B and in the next call, it tries the next answer for A (namely `s(s(s(0)))`) and so on.
Now the thing is, that I want Prolog to stop, if it founds an answer for A, and only searches now for an answer for B.

Can anybody give me a hint, how to solve this?

Comment: Typo: `numberpairD` --> `numberpair`?

Comment: ah yeah, sorry ...

Comment: This doesn't have an answer because your query doesn't make sense. You're asking Prolog to somehow magically see the future of the query. It can only succeed for one goal at a time. You can't make it fail on the third goal (`B=s(s(s(0)))`) and have it backtrack to the first goal (`numberpair(pair(A,B))`) but to skip over the second goal (`A=s(s(0))`) while backtracking. You need to redefine your query so that it makes sense.

Comment: @lurker: Not. The `D` was a very broad hint how to solve this.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The query does make sense. It reads: When being asked for **all** solutions, will this particular solution be found as well. In other words, is the enumeration fair or unfair.

Comment: @false ok, yeah, it was pretty broad. :p

Comment: @false - Theoretically, you're right, but in practical terms this never will produce a result and thus doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Please, have a look at the answer below! This is a very general method which can be applied whereever more efficient methods fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** As false pointed out:
<s>The reason you won't find an answer is that your rule numberpair/1 won't terminate.</s> The reason you won't find an answer is that Prolog enumerates your answer in a way that it first lists all possibilities for A and then the possibilities for B (note that both have infinite possibilities).  What Prolog tries is to find an answer first for the clause numberpair(pair(A,B)) but and then for the following clauses A=s(s(0)) and B=s(s(s(0))). But since numberpair already won't terminate, it won't "come" so far.

If you change the order of your <s>clauses</s> goals and simply call A=s(s(0)) before numberpair(pair(A,B)), it will give list you all answers for the possibilities of B (note that this still won't terminate!).

```
?- A=s(s(0)), numberpair(pair(A,B)).

A = s(s(0)),
B = 0 ;
A = s(s(0)),
B = s(0) ;
A = B, B = s(s(0)) ;
A = s(s(0)),
B = s(s(s(0))) .
```

**Edit 2**, to provide also a version, which will enumerates in a "fair" way!

```
is_number(0).
is_number(s(N)) :-
  is_number(N).

number_number_sum(0,A,A).
number_number_sum(s(A),B,s(C)) :-
    number_number_sum(A,B,C).

numberpair(pair(X,Y)) :-
    is_number(Z),
    number_number_sum(X,Y,Z).
```

Which will provide us with

```
?- numberpair(pair(A,B)).
A = B, B = 0 ;
A = 0,
B = s(0) ;
A = s(0),
B = 0 ;
A = 0,
B = s(s(0)) ;
A = B, B = s(0) ;
A = s(s(0)),
B = 0 ;
A = 0,
B = s(s(s(0))) ;
A = s(0),
B = s(s(0)) ;
A = s(s(0)),
B = s(0) ;
A = s(s(s(0))),
B = 0 .
```

Comment: Okay, seams logical to me.

Comment: »  The reason you won't find an answer is that your rule numberpair/1 won't terminate. «  That is not the reason - as you concede at the end. The reason is that the infinite set of number pairs is enumerated in a very unfair manner. So the goal here is to find a **fair enumeration** for numberpair/1.

Comment: would a fair enumeration be something like that:
A=0,           B=0
A=s(0),       B=0
A=0,           B=s(0)
A=s(s(0)),   B=0
A=s(0),       B=s(0)
A=0,           B=s(s(0))
... and so on

More specific: I try to move threw the search tree via "breadth-first search" and not via "depth-first-search"

Comment: Nice! Just note that you had to pay a price for this!